# using ripgrep with regex including literal dollar symbol

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, ripgrep

Suppose I have a script containing something like

```
VAR=${VAR1%.*}
```

I'm looking for a command along the lines of

```
rg "${.*%"
```

to find it, but I can't get anywhere near.

all of these fail

```
rg "\$\{.\*%"
rg \$\{.\*%
rg "\$\{.*%"
rg \$\{.*%
```

Comment: Use single quotes

Comment: rg '\$\{.*%' does the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$`, `\` are special to regular expressions and to the shell (including within double quotes for the latter). `{` is also special to the shell in some contexts, the list of which varies with the shell.

In fact, a lot of the regexp operators (`*`, `?`, `|`, `{`, `}`, `(`, `)`, `\`, `^`, `$`, `[` and `]` at least) are also special in the shell syntax (*some* shells anyway), so it's good practice to enclose regexps inside single quotes inside which, in most shells, all characters lose their special meaning if any.

So:

```
rg '\$\{.*%'
```

Where `'...'` escapes *all* characters for the shell (of those, `\` (quoteing operator), `$` (expansion operator) and `*` (glob operator) are special, sometimes `%` (job expansion operator)) and `\` escapes the `$` and `{` for the regexp.

Alternatively:

```
rg '[$][{].*%'
```

`rg` understands `perl`-like regular expressions for which `{x,y}` is a special operator like in modern extended regular expressions. Beware however that in *basic* regular expressions as understood by `grep` without `-E`/`-P`/`-A`/`-X`, `{`/`}` are not special but `\{`, `\}` are! So you must **not** escape the `{`/`}` of them to be treated literally in `grep` (or `sed`/`ed`/`ex`/`vi`... by default).

You may want to change your regexp to:

```
rg '\$\{[^}]*%'
```

Where we replaced `.` (matches any single character), with `[^}]` (matches any single character other than `}`) for it to avoid matching inside:

```
Item ${foo} is 20% cheaper than item ${bar}
```

For instance.

Looking at your attempts:

- *`rg "\$\{.\*%"`*, that's the same as `rg '$\{.\*%'` in most shells, as `\` is used by the shell to remove its special meaning to `$` there. `\` is kept in front of `{` and `*` as those characters are not special inside doubles quotes.
- *`rg \$\{.\*%`*, same as `rg '${.*%'`. `\` outside of quotes is just another quoting operator. `\x` is like `'x'` (newline, and sometimes `` ` `` and `!` being special cases). In the `fish` shell, `\` can also be used for `\n`, `\t`, `\a`, `\377`... escape sequences.
- *`rg "\$\{.*%"`*, same as `rg '$\{.*%'`, that was close
- *`rg \$\{.*%`* would be the worse one as the `*` globbing operator ends up being unquoted so the shell could expand it to the list of files whose name starts with `${` and ends in `%` in the current working directory.